# How to merge two bitmaps

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

Im trying to glue one bitmap on the right of second. Here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap getGluedBitmap(File left, File right, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache)
    {
        Bitmap lefty = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(left, reqWidth / 2, reqHeight, 2, mCache);
        Bitmap righty = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(right, reqWidth / 2, reqHeight, 2, mCache);
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(reqWidth, reqHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawBitmap(lefty, null, new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight()), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(righty, null, new Rect(canvas.getWidth() / 2 + 1, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), null);

        return output;
    }
```

And here is `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` method from Google examples, optimized for my needs:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(File file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, int state, LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache) {
        String imageKey = String.valueOf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        imageKey += state;
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey, mCache);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            boolean done = false;
            while(!done)
            {
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                    done = true;
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    // Ignore.  Try again.
                }
            }
            return addBitmapToMemoryCache(imageKey, bitmap, mCache);
        }
        else
        {
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

This method searches picture by key in cache, `state` is used to cache different versions on picters, i.e. little version, big vertion, etc.
Also, you can see some crooked nails with decoding file, but this step is temporary, and I'll fix this later. All you need to know that this method working 146% correctly.

The problem is: bitmap, that I'm creating with first method is uncorrect, and its not displaying. I mean width and height of this bitmap equals -1 for some reason.
However, width of Bitmap lefty and righty equals -1 too, but I've tryed display those bitmaps and that worked perfectly.

Tell me if I'm merging bitmaps wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code is absolutelly correct. For some reason, my device cant display the resulting bitmap. I tried to build this code to other device, and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your attention.